# Android textview height and checkbox in listview

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, textview

I have a custom listview with a textview and a checkbox. This is the xml file:

```
 <TextView android:id="@+id/rowTextView"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:background="#222222"/>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/CheckBox01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    >
</CheckBox>
```

Result:

[image]

I added a bg color to textview to see its height. Problem is when I click around the textview (the black space) the checkbox gets (un)checked. When I click on the textview, the checkbox remains state. I tried to extend the height of the textview (40dip) but it resulted in this:

[image]

How can I set the height of textview to the height of the checkbox?

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution. Not perfect, but it's working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <TextView android:id="@+id/rowTextView" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="15dip"
    android:paddingBottom="15dip"
    android:background="#222222">
  </TextView>

  <CheckBox android:id="@+id/CheckBox01" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginRight="6sp"
    android:focusable="false">
  </CheckBox>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to keep both textView and CheckBox in different linear layouts. And check, this may solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can set custom style to the button with lower padding values then the default one.
You can set margin for the button.
You can set a fixed DP value for the buttons height.

style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        ...
        />